# Remove all but selected words regexp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
PL
--
PRIMARY A&B
SECONDARY B&C
TERTIARY C&D
```

And I would like to have the below output (removing all but 'PRIMARY' or 'SECONDARY' or 'TERTIARY').

```
PL
--
PRIMARY
SECONDARY
TERTIARY
```

So far, I've tried the below, but struggling to make it work.

```
with aux (pl) as (
    select 'PRIMARY A&B' from dual union all
    select 'SECONDARY B&C' from dual union all
    select 'TERTIARY C&D' from dual)
SELECT
    regexp_replace(pl, '[^[PRIMARY]|^[SECONDARY]|^[TERTIARY]]', NULL) j
FROM
    aux;
```

Comment: What happens when those words are not in `pl`?  What if the words appears multiple times?  What if they are not at the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

Look for string starting with PRIMARY or SECONDARY or TERTIARY and put it between round brackets so you can backreference it. Then backreference it with \1. The `(.*)` will match everything after it.

```
with aux (pl) as (
    select 'PRIMARY A&B' from dual union all
    select 'SECONDARY B&C' from dual union all
    select 'TERTIARY C&D' from dual)
SELECT
    regexp_replace(pl, '^(PRIMARY|SECONDARY|TERTIARY)(.*)', '\1') j
FROM
    aux;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it (I don't know whether reality reflects sample data you posted), isn't regexp overkill? Select substring up to the first space:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'PRIMARY A&B'   from dual union all
  3     select 'SECONDARY B&C' from dual union all
  4     select 'TERTIARY C&D'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         substr(col, 1, instr(col, ' ') - 1) result
  8  from test;

COL           RESULT
------------- -------------
PRIMARY A&B   PRIMARY
SECONDARY B&C SECONDARY
TERTIARY C&D  TERTIARY

SQL>
```

If it isn't that simple, consider posting better sample data & more precise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a regular expression is the right way to go.  Your question is a bit vague on details, but you might just want:

```
select (case when pl like 'PRIMARY%' then 'PRIMARY'
             when pl like 'SECONDARY%' then 'SECONDARY'
             when pl like 'TERTIARY%' then 'TERTIARY'
        end) as new_pl
```

This would "classify" the `pl` values based on starting with one of the special strings.  Your question is unclear on several points:

- Do you only care about the strings at the beginning of the column?
- Do the strings need to be followed by a space to be valid?
- What happens when the column doesn't contain one of the values?

(I do realize that this can be accomplished with a regular expression as well.)